# Splitting the datatable into multiple datatables

Tags: c#, linq

These are the contents of my datatable `dtAllData`.

```
 column_1  column_2  column_3    
 --------  --------  --------  
 sec_1       Test1        2
 sec_1       Result1      5
 sec_1       Unit1        2 
 sec_2       Test2        2           
 sec_2       Result2      2
 sec_2       Unit2        5
 sec_3       Test3        2 
 sec_3       Result3      2     
 sec_3       Unit3        2
```

I need to split it into multiple datatables on the basis of contents in column `column_1`.

So in this case I'm supposed to get 3 tables (one having all rows with `sec_1`, other with `sec_2` & another with `sec_3`).

I tried this:

```
var dtArray = dtAllData.AsEnumerable() 
                            .GroupBy(row => new
                            {
                                column_1 = (string)row["column_1"]
                            });
DataTable[] array = new DataTable[dtArray.Count()];
```

How can I get tables in `array` from `dtArray`?

Comment: What is purpose of that split? In ASA/ASE databases (Sybase products) replication based on some column is possible. Im not SQLServer specialisty, but maybe SqlServer have similar functionality?

Comment: You write _I need to split it into multiple datatables_ after _I'm supposed to get 3 tables_ you want to split in multiple database or tables ? Why you want to group ? You simply filter table by where clausole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `CopyToDataTable()` method to get the data into a new DataTable.

```
var Result =  from x in dtAllData.AsEnumerable()
              where x.Field<string>("column_1") == "sec_1"
              select x;
DataTable t1 = Result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Another way is using `LoadDataRow()` method. [Here is an example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/6d4e2579-f4b5-497c-ad00-7c347eb1f902)

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?

Comment: @kaf i use this solution in datatable with 5 million rows but i get out of memory exception, can i help me to avoid this exception, i need a solution to manage this with memory optimized way

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact names of column_1 you can use [.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) `.Select("column_1 = sec_1")`etc. or use a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `Kaf`'s solution, I achieved what I wanted as:

```
var uniqueList = dtAllData.AsEnumerable().Select(x=> x.Field<string>("column_1")).Distinct();
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList =uniqueList.ToList();

DataTable[] array = new DataTable[myList.Count()];
int index = 0;
foreach (string item in myList)
{
    var Result =  from x in dtAllData.AsEnumerable()
                  where x.Field<string>("column_1") == item
                  select x;
    DataTable table = Result.CopyToDataTable();
    array[index] = table;
    index++;
}
```

So the `array` contains 3 datatables with different values of `column_1`

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?

Answer (score -2):

```
Function splitDataTable(ByVal tbl As DataTable) As DataTable()
    Dim tableCount = Math.Ceiling(tbl.Rows.Count / NewCountRows)

    Dim Divisor = tbl.Rows.Count / tableCount
    Dim tables = tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r, i) New With {.row = r, .index = i}).GroupBy(Function(x) Math.Floor(x.index / Divisor)).Select(Function(g) g.Select(Function(x) x.row).CopyToDataTable())
    Return tables.ToArray
End Function
```